# How to match view by RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, dns, bind9

***named.conf***

```
options {
            listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;};
            listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
            directory       "/var/named";
            dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
            statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
            memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    };

    view lan {
            match-clients {localhost;};

            zone "home.com" IN {
                   type master;
                   file "home.zone";
            };

            zone "test.com" IN {
                   type master;
                   file "test.com.zone";
            };

            zone    "demo.local" IN {
                    type master;
                    file "f.demo.local";
                    allow-update { none; };
            };
            zone    "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
                    type master;
                    file "r.demo.local";
                    allow-update { none; };
            };
    };

    view wireless{
            match-clients {localhost;};

            zone    "home.com" IN {
                    type master;
                    file "home2.zone";
            };
    };

    include "/etc/rndc.key";
```

In the future may be more views and zone. How to use RegExp to match separate view in named.conf file

Group 1 :

> view lan { ... };

Group 2 :

> view wireless { ... };

Thank You!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
var regexp = /(?:\n| )*view[\s\S\n\r ]+?(?=\n+ *view|$)/g
```

Comment: @AnurakJairak: But a `/\s*view[\s\S]+?(?=\n+\s*view|$)/g` version is cleaner.

Comment: I'm test yet, it's work too. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

Assuming node.js environment

```
var namedConf = fs.readFileSync('named.conf');

var matches = namedConf.match(/view lan {(.*)};\s*view wireless{(.*)}/);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But  it's incomprehensive in the future if more view and zone